# Why is Shift+Backpace logging me out?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, shortcut-keys

Ever since my update to 12.04, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> ends my X Session/Logs me out. How can I stop this?

Comment: Is, by any chance, one of your <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys stuck?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have fixed the issue:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = BackSpace BackSpace Terminate_Server"

xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap
```